# Is there a preferred JavaScript method for detecting screen size in a browser?

Tags: javascript

I have been looking at way to detect what screen size I am working with for a website. i.e. iPhone, desktop, tablet, etc.

So far I have come across quite a few methods. I am just looking to see if there is a preferred method, one that is more universal, etc. I realize there is rarely a one size fits all method. Just looking for the best.

If it makes a difference, the website will be a very minimalistic website. It's more of an add-on page for an app. So there will no bells and whistles on it.

```
window.innerWidth
...
screen.width 
...
document.body.clientWidth
...
window.outerWidth;
```

Comment: "I realize there is rarely a one size fits all method. Just looking for the best." Well, if you know there is no one size fits all method, then you should know there is no "best". There is only "best for this particular set of circumstances". Since you have no particular set of circumstances, there is no "best". All of those things measure different dimensions.

Comment: "Why" do you need to detect...screen size?   To style components differently?  Can you use CSS media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` = the inner width of your current window (as you adjust the size it will give you the actual width of the window itself... ideal for responsive development).

`screen.width` = the size of your actual screen.

For application development, I'd recommend utilizing `window.innerWidth`.